# Paypal Express checkout error in production

Tags: reactjs, paypal, gatsby

I am integrating **Paypal express checkout** with **gatsby(reactjs)** it's perfectly working fine with sandbox accounts but not in **production**. It gives me the following error

[image: Console log errors]

My code is

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import PaypalExpressBtn from "react-paypal-express-checkout"
import notify from "../functions/notify"
import Api from "../functions/API"
import fbTrack from "../functions/fbTrack"

const client = {
  sandbox: "sanbox_key",
  production: "prod_key",
}

export default ({ plan, setUserData, setBillingHistory, setUserContact }) => {

  const onSuccess = (payment) => {
    const data = {
      payment,
      plan,
    }
    notify("The payment was succeeded!")

    try {
      fbTrack("track", "Purchase", plan.price)
    } catch (e) {
      // do nothing
    }

    // Sending the res call
    Api.fetch("post", "make-payment-paypal", data).then(() => {
      Api.fetch()
        .then(user => {
          setUserData(user)
        })

      Api.fetch("get", "get-contact")
        .then(contact => {
          setUserContact(contact)
        })

      Api.fetch("get", "get-billing-history")
        .then(billing => {
          setBillingHistory(billing)
        })
    }).catch(e => console.log(e))
  }

  const onCancel = (data) => {
    notify("The payment was cancelled", "danger")
  }

  const onError = (err) => {
    notify("Error occurred. Please retry.", "danger")
  }

  return <PaypalExpressBtn env={"production"} client={client} currency={plan.currency_code} total={plan.price} onError={onError}
                           onSuccess={onSuccess} onCancel={onCancel}/>
}
```

Response from network tab for /execute endpoint that gives 400

```
{
  "ack": "contingency",
  "contingency": "INSTRUMENT_DECLINED",
  "meta": {
    "calc": "e8cc408a47d1f",
    "rlog": "rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUueWscmrtUHe5Y1Bd%2FeqyvyOTq66rSXAcvMRdZesXq1O38dITQfoakLPn1nG4pMu0qURH%2Be5YB%2B4_1709bb5bb49"
  },
  "server": "2mEzKB-B1lh9-OtP-2sBI96A-5Xu_ZnMt0Rz1fJ2a4n4noKlAHLadCNfrWklmy5YUKipx6UR0bGzcI9u9Q-a4b1v4LHPM9g6W4a6WmXYuh9wqhRDdbsHbYSzXX8ucZU3a4Xp-wZrSy6qYgnEZoDKzjuz_fjiBvxhxD2fNlGbF5tm_h_xd-G9FaYynEq4jwg1MYcCAXMgLLsxc2J81gNfe01GF7FRInwK5mbgWxtwed9fOwRRfBycXsn_diFRBuIJR7UEXAfmeZYIzkBATQbYfm"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "ack": "contingency",
  "contingency": "INSTRUMENT_DECLINED",
  "meta": {
    "calc": "e8cc408a47d1f",
    "rlog": "rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUueWscmrtUHe5Y1Bd%2FeqyvyOTq66rSXAcvMRdZesXq1O38dITQfoakLPn1nG4pMu0qURH%2Be5YB%2B4_1709bb5bb49"
  },
  "server": "2mEzKB-B1lh9-OtP-2sBI96A-5Xu_ZnMt0Rz1fJ2a4n4noKlAHLadCNfrWklmy5YUKipx6UR0bGzcI9u9Q-a4b1v4LHPM9g6W4a6WmXYuh9wqhRDdbsHbYSzXX8ucZU3a4Xp-wZrSy6qYgnEZoDKzjuz_fjiBvxhxD2fNlGbF5tm_h_xd-G9FaYynEq4jwg1MYcCAXMgLLsxc2J81gNfe01GF7FRInwK5mbgWxtwed9fOwRRfBycXsn_diFRBuIJR7UEXAfmeZYIzkBATQbYfm"
}
```

This means the card was declined.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is there is no problem with the card and I checked with multiple accounts.

Comment: Nevertheless, the card was declined. You need to contact PayPal if you want to find out more. Not an issue for Stack Overflow.